# How to center elements in cellview in iCarousel?

Tags: ios, icarousel

I have three UI elements on top of each other (one button and two text labels) that I want to center in a view of iCarousel. I've tried using NSLayoutContraits like this:

```
[self.backgroundView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.backgroundView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                 constant:0]];

[self.backgroundView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.descriptionLabel
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.backgroundView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               multiplier:1
                                                                 constant:0]];
```

But it's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.backgroundView setCenter:CGPointMake(xcoord, ycoord)];
```

That should do the job